# Incentives for rating in Google play

Tags: google-play

I just wanted to put a rate game pop up in my game in Google play. Is giving incentives for rating game in Google play illegal? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google Play terms of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The should be absolutely nothing wrong with that, except for the chance that users are getting annoyed by it and give the app a worse rating ;)